# Collections shuffle dont shuffle 0, ond R.drawable propertly

Tags: java, arrays, image, shuffle

```
 I have a lot of questions in list callesd `Quesl`. When I write down `Collections.shuffle(Quesl);` list gets randomized, but parts where I have `0` and `R.drawable` for `images` gets randomized on its own, unrelated to other strings in current question, and so I get pictures from unrelated questions on other questions. Is there a way to randomize list without this type of interference?



    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME1 = "Bio";

    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST1 = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question1";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; // correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA = "opta"; // option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB = "optb"; // option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC = "optc"; // option c
    private static final String KEY_OPTD = "optd"; // option d
    private static final String KEY_OPTE = "opte"; // option e

    private SQLiteDatabase dbase1;

    public BiologijaPitanja (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME1, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase bio) {
        dbase1 = bio;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST1 + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT," + KEY_OPTD
                + " TEXT," + KEY_OPTE + " TEXT)";

        bio.execSQL(sql);

        addQuestions();
    }

    private void addQuestions()
    {  
Question q19 = new Question("Koja je uloga dijela bubrega označenoga na slici slovom F.?",
        R.drawable.pit19biojes201314,
        "filtracija krvi",
        "skupljanje urina",
        "dovođenje krvi",
        "odvođenje krvi",
        "skupljanje urina");
    this.addQuestion(q19);

    Question q20 = new Question("Koja reakcija prethodi nastanku ureje?", 
         0,
         "razgradnja glukoze",
         "deaminacija proteina",
         "sinteza pirogrožđane kiseline",
         "oksidacija limunske kiseline",
         "deaminacija proteina");
    this.addQuestion(q20);


}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase bio, int oldV1, int newV1) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        bio.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST1);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(bio);
    }

    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest1) {
        // SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest1.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest1.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest1.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest1.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest1.getOPTC());
        values.put(KEY_OPTD, quest1.getOPTD());
        values.put(KEY_OPTE, quest1.getOPTE());

        // Inserting Row
        dbase1.insert(TABLE_QUEST1, null, values);
    }

    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesListBio = new ArrayList<Question>();

        String selectQuery1 = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST1;
        dbase1 = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase1.rawQuery(selectQuery1, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest1 = new Question();
                quest1.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest1.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest1.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest1.setOPTA(cursor.getInt(3));
                quest1.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest1.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quest1.setOPTD(cursor.getString(6));
                quest1.setOPTE(cursor.getString(7));
                quesListBio.add(quest1);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        return quesListBio;
    }

    public int rowcount1() {
        int row1 = 0;
        String selectQuery1 = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST1;
        SQLiteDatabase bio = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = bio.rawQuery(selectQuery1, null);
        row1 = cursor.getCount();
        return row1;
    }

}







In main activity there is shuffle method
```

on crerate blahblah...

```
 BiologijaPitanja bio=new BiologijaPitanja(this);
        quesListBio=bio.getAllQuestions();
      Collections.shuffle(quesListBio);
        currentQ=quesListBio.get(qid);
```

I tried exchange 0 to 1,2,3,4,5,6, etc it doesnt work and now even when i remove shuffle method it does not return to normal state. Before i tried to implement shuffle method it worked normally

Comment: Can you give us more of your code? It is easier to help with all the code.

Comment: What do you mean by: 0 and R.drawable for images gets randomized on its own, unrelated to other strings in current question? Presumably you are just shuffling a list of questions?

Comment: yes they exchange unrelated to other strings in current qurestion, and yes i am shuffling a list